# Returning the value of button from a class using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I'm trying to select a value using the button. How do I return the value of 'option' from the class? Thanks

I would like to have something like my_gui_value=option_box(root).option
Thanks

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class option_box:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.train_button = Button(master,text="Training",command=self.train)
        self.train_button.pack()

        self.test_button = Button(master, text="Testing", command=self.test)
        self.test_button.pack()

    def train(self):
        option=0
        print option
    def test(self):
        option=1
        print option

root = Tk()
my_gui = option_box(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you plan to put this proposed `my_gui_value=...` line? Keep in mind that any code that appears after `root.mainloop()` will not execute until after the window has closed.

Answer (score 1):

Save it instead of returning it.

```
def train(self):
    self.option = 0
    print self.option
def test(self):
    self.option = 1
    print self.option
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I call it from another script? Basically I want to import this to another program. I would like the class to return one or zero to the main program every time I make a section

Comment: Access the object and its attributes like any other: `ob = option_box(root)`, `ob.option`. You will of course have to make adjustments to fit your program.